# Why does ReSharper default to boolean when extracting a new method?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

As I was refactoring some old code and extracting logic into methods using ReSharper's create method, I have noticed that whenever my method needs to return something back the default return type in the signature is always boolean.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this is so?

Why wouldn't it default to something more generic such as object?

This is not an urgent problem that I need to solve, but since I admire working with this tool I would like to know more about it.

Is it just a choice JetBrains made based on some statistical data or is there something more subtle that I am missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean "method needs to return something". When you extract method it is always clear what return type should be. Please consider adding sample code where you see R# suggesting different signature than what you expect.

Comment: is this happen when you extract method from your code? it depends on your code.resharper decides depending on usage of variables. it can be void or anything. its not set to boolean as default. its what resharper suggest. you maybe able to change it or not. it depends on the code and witch part you want to extract